# Highlight active (opened) link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highlight

I want to highlight active (opened) link . This color must be maintained for all time when link is open. Not only on mouse click or hover.

**Here is JS way what i tried:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a.nav1").click(function () {
      $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    });
</script>
```

**html links:**

```
 <div id="navigation">              
          <ul>
          <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#home" id="link-home"href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#football" id="link-football" href="#football">Football</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#hockey" id="link-hockey"href="#hockey">Hockey</a
</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

It work but the problem is with refresh and back button. It does not change this color to previous link.
With other JS ways i got same problem.

Only with css it does not work. For example:

```
  <div id="navigation">             
              <ul>
              <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#home" id="link-home"href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#football" id="link-football" href="#football">Football</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#hockey" id="link-hockey"href="#hockey">Hockey</a
    </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
```

**and CSS**

```
#home .nav1 {
    color: #000;
    background-image:url(farba3.png);
 }
#football .nav1 {
    color: #000;
    background-image:url(farba3.png);
 }
#hockey .nav1 {
    color: #000;
    background-image:url(farba3.png);
 }
```

Comment: why dont you use the `a:visited` pseudo? this stays even after page-refresh, as far as I know.

Comment: @Homungus: how would that help the OP?

Comment: @LéoLam: I thought he wants to highlight a visited/opened link, doesnt he? thats what the style-pseudo `a:visited` does.

Comment: `a:visited` would end up highlighting all links, if the user clicked (that means visited) all links.

Comment: no it is not what i want. a:visited change color visited link but i want change color opened link (specific color must stay while link is open)

Comment: So what about `.nav1.active { //css color change }`?

Comment: gbishop3: it is not working without JS and with JS is problem with back/ refresh button.

Comment: ah ok you just want to highlight LAST clicked anchor. ok. Does the document-ready event occur if user hits back-button? anyone knows that?

Answer (score 3):

**You'll want to listen for hash change events (`window.onhashchange`), and change the active link accordingly.**

Here's an example:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    $('.nav1').removeClass('active'); // remove the active class from all elements
    $('.nav1[href="' + location.hash + '"]').addClass('active'); // add the active class to the element whose href equals the new fragment identifier ("hashtag")
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged; // listen for hash change event
locationHashChanged(); // add the active class to the appropriate link on initial page load
```

Then, in your CSS, you'll add a rule for the list items who have the `.active` class.

Want to try it? [There you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/9KKrQ/1/)

Note that the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) is available and allows for clean, nice URLs. Why not use it? Using fragment identifiers is outdated and not nice for those who happen to have JS disabled.

If you really want to use the history API and are worried about [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), you can use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/), which makes using the history API possible even with browsers that don't support it. For more info, please see the repository.

Comment: @Fakt7: has this helped you? Just wanted to know if this helped you or not, and if not, I'll try to improve the answer.

Comment: @Fakt7: I've edited the code, so it now adds the active class to the appropriate link on initial page load. I've also added a live example.

Answer (score 0):

Try cookies or localStorage, where you can write the link on click and read it on page load. There are several jQuery plugins for this, like [Storage API](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API).

Comment: local storage/ session storage resolve refresh button problem.HistoryAPI  resolve back button problem  but it is not good idea. There is bad browsers support.

Comment: Because HTTP is state-less, I'm affraid for refresh some kind of storage you will need no matter what. And for Back I'm having some obscure ideas, like set a timer and check some attribs, like scroll position or visibility/display (to figure out what link should be highlighted)... - but of course it's a nasty and quite inefficient approach.

Comment: OK i found another one problem so i must use HistoryAPI. but how to do it. I tried window.history.back(); but without result

Comment: Invoke it by history.pushState(state_data_JSON, pageTitle, pageURL); and catch by window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {}); For "back" it should be possible to use window.history.back(); or window.history.go(-1); You can find an example on http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: @Fakt7: I've updated my answer to mention a solution based on the history API for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @Fakt7: If you want to use the history API but are having with it, it would be better to ask another question.

Comment: i created new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252490/how-to-use-historyapi-or-history-js-to-remain-previous-active-link-color-on-refr